# window scroll method flickers in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, scroll

This may come as a huge surprise to some people but I am having an issue with the IE browser when I am using the `$(window).scroll` method.

My goal:
I would like to have the menu located on the left retain it's position until the scroll reaches > y value. It will then fix itself to the top of the page until the scroll returns to a < y value.

My error:
Everything seems just fine in Chrome and Firefox but when I go to Internet Explorer it would seem the browser is moving #scroller every time the scroll value changes, this is causing a moving/flickering event.

If someone could point me to a resource or give me a workaround for this I would be very grateful!

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CampbeII/nLK7j/

Here is a link to the site in dev:
http://squ4reone.com/domains/ottawakaraoke/Squ4reone/responsive/index.php

My script:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var navigation = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (navigation > 400) {
        $('#scroller').css('top',navigation - 220);
    } else {
        $('#scroller').css('top',183);
        $('#scroller').css('position','relative');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) plugin, it lets you do [sticky elements](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) like this and a lot more.

If you want to stick with your current method, like the other answers have indicated you should toggle `fixed` positioning instead of updating the `.top` attribute in every scroll event. However, I would also introduce a flag to track whether or not it is currently stuck, this way you are only updating the `position` and `top` attributes when it actually make the transition instead of every scroll event. Interacting with the DOM is computationally expensive, this will take a lot of load off of the layout engine and should make things even smoother.

http://jsfiddle.net/WYNcj/6/

```
$(function () {
  var stuck = false,
      stickAt = $('#scroller').offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function () {

    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (!stuck && scrollTop > stickAt) {
      $('#scroller').css('top', 0);
      $('#scroller').css('position','fixed');
      stuck = true;
    } else if (stuck && scrollTop < stickAt) {
      $('#scroller').css('top', stickAt);
      $('#scroller').css('position','absolute');
      stuck = false;
    }
  });
});
```

## Update

Switching the `#scroller` from `relative` to `fixed` removes it from the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow) of the page, this can have unintended consequences for the layout as it re-flows without the missing block. If you change `#scroller` to use an [`absolute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning) `position` it will be removed from the normal flow and will no longer cause these side-effects. I've updated the above example and the linked jsfiddle to reflect the changes to the JS/CSS.

I also changed the way that `stickAt` is calculated as well, it uses [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to find the exact position of the top of `#scoller` instead of relying on the CSS top value.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I was wondering if you could maybe offer a little more insight when it comes to this line
 
stickAt = parseInt($('#scroller').css('top'), 10);

Does this mean that #scroller will stickAt top:10px, 10%? The reason I ask is because I noticed that when I implemented the code there was a small overlap that occurred over the header and the positioning kicked in too early when scrolled.

When I tried to change that value to say 20 #scroller stuck too far down. So my question is if I would like the event triggered 20px farther down what would I change that value to?

Comment: Here is the updated site with your suggested code
www.squ4reone.com/domains/ottawakaraoke/Squ4reone/responsive/index.php

If you scroll somewhat slowly you can see that when switched to fixed pos it overlaps

Comment: `parseInt($('#scroller').css('top'), 10);` gets the `top` attribute of `#scroller`, which is a string, [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) converts it to an integer. I think a couple of things are happening there. First, it is sticking early because there is a header above it, that provides an extra offset in addition to what `css('top')` returns. Then, the body of the page jumping up into the header is a result of `#scroller` being removed from the normal flow of the page.

Comment: Using `$('#scroller').offset().top;` instead of `parseInt($('#scroller').css('top'), 10);` would probably solve the first problem. To solve the second problem, you could replace `#scroller` with a place holder like waypoints does but it would be better/easier to just take `#scroller` out of the normal flow altogether by making it `position: absolute` rather than `relative`, which would solve both problems at the same time. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: In regard to the `10` in `parseInt($('#scroller').css('top'), 10);`, it is the `radix`, it tells `parseInt` that the number it is parsing is a decimal number. If you ever use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), [always use a radix](http://www.michaelgaigg.com/blog/2008/10/07/the-importance-of-the-javascript-parseint-radix/)!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the top distance at each scroll event, please consider only switching between a fixed position and an absolute or relative position.All browsers will appreciate and Especially IE.

So you still listen to scroll but you now keep a state flag out of the scroll handler and simply evaluate if it has to switch between display types.

That is so much more optimized and IE likes it.

Answer (score 0):

I can get flickers in Chrome as well if I scroll very quickly. Instead of updating the top position on scroll, instead used the `fixed` position for your element once the page has scrolled below the threshold. Take a look at the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLK7j/2/